# Receiving 401 "Bad Credentials" when hitting github API endpoint

Tags: node.js, github, request

I'm trying to build a CLI that uses the GitHub api.  I instantly run into a road block.  Although I've read the introductory docs up and down, I don't see what is wrong in the following code.

```
var userData = require('../userData');
var request = require('request');

module.exports = {
  hitEndpoint: function() {
    var username = "<redacted_user_name>",
        password = "<redacted_password>",
        auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64");

    var options = {
      method: 'get',
      url: " https://api.github.com/<redacted_user_name>",
      headers: {
        "Authorization": auth,
        "User-Agent": "<redacted_whatever_doesnt_matter>"
      }
    }
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
      console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
      console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
      console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
    });

  },
}
```

prints:

```
error: null
statusCode: 404
body: {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}
```

Comment: Is the endpoint you're trying to hit is https://api.github.com/username rather than https://api.github.com/users/username, I can't tell whether you redacted just the username or the full path?

Comment: it looks like if i run the same request hitting `/users/<redacted_user_name>`  i do get a response.  however, originally that was the full path.  in GH's docs under "Get Your Own User Profile"  `curl -i -u your_username https://api.github.com/user`

Comment: It's saying you should hit the endpoint `https://api.github.com/user` which will return your profile, not replace it with your own username :)

Comment: another question I have, which I am unclear about after reading the docs, is whether basic authentication is sufficient for all API operations, seeing as they talk a lot about OAuth and of "being authenticated".  i'm unclear about the meaning that one can "be authenticated" under basic auth if the auth credentials are passed in at the same time as the request.

Comment: You can use either basic authentication or OAuth2, they will both work for the entire API.

Comment: ah.. i'm terrible at reading http docs.. i do mostly UI hehe ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your own profile you'll want to hit the [authenticated user endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-the-authenticated-user), you shouldn't replace this with your own username, GitHub will know who you are based on your authentication string:

```
https://api.github.com/user
```

To get another user's profile you'll want to hit the [users endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/):

```
https://api.github.com/users/:username
```